# Определить размер файла, требуемый для сохранения списка объектов

Tags: c#, сериализация

Есть список объектов, который нужно сохранить в файл. Могу сохранять в файлы трех типов: текстовые, бинарные и xml. Нужен метод, который будет определять размер файлов, содержащих мой список объектов. Т.е. у меня есть список объектов, который я хочу сохранить в файл, я вызываю этот метод, а он мне сообщает: сколько памяти потребуется для текстового файла, сколько для бинарного и сколько для xml-файла. Поля моего класса:

```
[Serializable]
public class Equipment
{
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    int amount;
    double unitCost;
    double totalCost;
}
```

Методы для записи файлов:

```
    public static void WriteTxtFile(List<Equipment> equipments, string path)
    {
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path, false))
        {
            equipments.ForEach(equipment => writer.WriteLine($"{equipment.Department};{equipment.Name};{equipment.Amount};{equipment.UnitCost};{equipment.TotalCost}"));
        }
    }

    public static void WriteBinaryFile(List<Equipment> equipments, string path)
    {
        using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)))
        {
            foreach(Equipment equipment in equipments)
            {
                writer.Write(equipment.Department);
                writer.Write(equipment.Name);
                writer.Write(equipment.Amount);
                writer.Write(equipment.UnitCost);
                writer.Write(equipment.TotalCost);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void WriteXmlFile(List<Equipment> equipments, string path)
    {
        XmlSerializer formatter = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Equipment>));
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            formatter.Serialize(fs, equipments);
        }
    }
```

Comment: А что вам нужно, и что не получается?

Comment: Можно сначала сохранить список в нужных форматах в файлы, а затем уже с помощью `FileInfo.Length` определить размер файла в байтах

Comment: Поясните вопрос, что за список объектов, какое отношение он имеет файлам?

Comment: То есть нужно определить размер будущего файла, не создавая самого файла? OK, понятно. Однако, реализация зависит от того, какие именно данные будут записываться и каким способом (форматирование, кодировка). Поэтому приведите пример исходных данных и то, как они будут записываться.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov обновил

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создайте свой класс, производный от Stream, который вместо записи данных будет считать их размер:

```
public class MyStream : Stream
{
    int c = 0;

    public override bool CanRead => false;

    public override bool CanSeek => false;

    public override bool CanWrite => true;

    public override long Length => с;

    public override long Position { get => c; set => throw new NotSupportedException(); }

    public override void Flush()
    {
        return;
    }

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public override void SetLength(long value)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        c += count;
    }
}
```

Создайте для каждого метода перегрузку, которая будет писать те же данные, но не в файл, а в Stream:

```
public static void WriteTxtFile(List<Equipment> equipments, Stream s)
{
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(s);
    equipments.ForEach(equipment => writer.WriteLine($"{equipment.Department};{equipment.Name};{equipment.Amount};{equipment.UnitCost};{equipment.TotalCost}"));
    writer.Flush();
}
```

Тогда размер данных вы сможете определить так:

```
MyStream s = new MyStream();            
WriteTxtFile(eqlist, s);
Console.WriteLine("Text file size: " + s.Position);
```

Comment: Заменил все `NotImplementedException` на `NotSupportedException`, потому что эти операции не просто не реализованы, а в принципе абсурдны для подобного потока.

Answer (score 1):

> есть список объектов, который я хочу сохранить в файл
>   сколько памяти потребуется для текстового файла, сколько для бинарного и сколько для xml-файла

Допустим, имеется следующий класс:

```
public class Equipment
{
    //public string Department { get; set; }
    //public string Name { get; set; }
    public int amount { get; set; }
    public double unitCost { get; set; }
    public double totalCost { get; set; }
}
```

И записывается он в бинарный файл с помощью [BinaryWriter](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.binarywriter?view=netframework-4.8):

```
binaryWriter.Write(equipment.amount);
binaryWriter.Write(equipment.unitCost);
binaryWriter.Write(equipment.totalCost);
```

То есть данные идут вплотную, без дополнительной метаинформации.

Размер примитивных типов можно получить оператором [sizeof](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/sizeof). Следовательно, размер одного экземпляра и всего списка вычисляется следующим образом:

```
int equipmentSize = sizeof(int) + sizeof(double) + sizeof(double);
int listSize = equipmentSize * equipmentList.Count;
```

O(1) - эффективнее некуда.

---

Однако, если раскомментировать строковые свойства, то ситуация усложнится.

Длина строки в байтах зависит от используемой кодировки (`BinaryWriter` может использовать любую). Следовательно, нужно вычислять эту длину.

```
int nameSize = encoding.GetByteCount(equipment.Name);
int departmentSize = encoding.GetByteCount(equipment.Department);
```

где `encoding` - та же кодировка, что используется при записи в файл.

Естественно, длина строк у разных объектов в списке может быть разная, поэтому придётся сделать проход по всему списку и добавить сумму длин в `listSize`. Получаем O(n).

Дело осложняется тем, что при записи строк в файл `BinaryWriter` предваряет значение записываемой строки её длиной. Это значение тоже нужно приплюсовать к итоговому размеру. Причём длина рассчитывается как 7-bit encoded. Подробнее [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47409296/5045688) и [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44401928/5045688).

---

Вычисление размера текстового файла зависит от используемой кодировки и от формата. Его сделать относительно несложно используя метод `Encoding.GetByteCount`.

XML-файл по сути является текстовым. Аналогично, его размер можно рассчитать аналитически, без самой записи. Но возникает много проблем с предварительным определением его формата: с индентацией и без, с переносом атрибутов на новую строку или без переноса и многое другое.

При желании, можно заморочиться ручным вычислением. Но это окупится лишь в том случае, если нужно рассчитывать размеры большого количества файлов/потоков большого размера. А главное, код в ответе MSDN.WhiteKnight именно это и делает.